# Writing a Virtual Serialize Function with a Base and Derived Class

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on a project to handle an inventory of cars.  There is a base Vehicle class and a derived AdvancedVehicle class.  I am running into an issue with my serialize function which is meant to be a virtual function.  It seems that whenever the function is called by either the base or derived class, it only runs the base serialize function.  Attached is both the Vehicle and AdvancedVehicle class definitions and implementations.

```
/////////////////////////////// VEHICLE //////////////////////////////////
class Vehicle{
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Vehicle v) {
            v.Serialize(os);
            return os;
    }
public:
    Vehicle() = delete;
    Vehicle(string model, size_t year, float price) {
        m_model = model;
        m_year = year;
        m_baseprice = price;
        m_owner = NULL;
    }
    Vehicle(string model, size_t year, float price, const Client* owner) {
        m_model = model;
        m_year = year;
        m_baseprice = price;
        m_owner = new Client("");
        *m_owner = *owner;
    }
    Vehicle(const Vehicle& otherVehicle) {
        m_model = otherVehicle.m_model;
        m_year = otherVehicle.m_year;
        m_baseprice = otherVehicle.m_baseprice;
        m_owner = NULL;
    }
    Vehicle& operator= (const Vehicle& otherVehicle) {
        m_model = otherVehicle.m_model;
        m_year = otherVehicle.m_year;
        m_baseprice = otherVehicle.m_baseprice;
        m_owner = new Client("");
        *m_owner = *otherVehicle.m_owner;
        return *this;
    }
    void setPrice(float price) {
        m_baseprice = price;
    }
    void SetOwner(const Client* owner) {
        m_owner = new Client("");
        if(owner)
        {
            *m_owner = *owner;
        }
    }
    string GetModel() const { return m_model; }
    size_t GetYear() const { return m_year; }
    virtual float GetPrice() const { return m_baseprice; }
    Client* GetOwner() const { return m_owner; }
    virtual void Serialize(ostream& os) const {
        os << m_year << " ";
        os << m_model << " ";
        os << m_baseprice << " ";
        if(m_owner != NULL)
        {
            os << *m_owner << endl;
        }
    }
protected:
    string m_model;
    size_t m_year;

private:
 float m_baseprice;
 Client* m_owner;
};



/////////////////////////// ADVANCEDVEHICLE ///////////////////////////////
class AdvancedVehicle : public Vehicle{
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const AdvancedVehicle AV) {
        AV.Serialize(os);
        return os;
    }
public:
    AdvancedVehicle() = delete;
    AdvancedVehicle(string model, size_t year, float price, vector<Sensor> sensors, const Client* owner):Vehicle (model, year, price){
        m_model = model;
        m_year = year;
        SetOwner(owner);
        setPrice(price);
        for(auto i = sensors.begin(); i != sensors.end(); i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            AddSensor(sensors[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    AdvancedVehicle(string model, size_t year, float price, vector<Sensor> sensors):Vehicle (model, year, price){
        m_model = model;
        m_year = year;
        SetOwner(NULL);
        setPrice(price);
        for(auto i = sensors.begin(); i != sensors.end(); i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            AddSensor(sensors[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    AdvancedVehicle(const AdvancedVehicle& otherAV):Vehicle( otherAV) {
        m_model = otherAV.m_model;
        m_year = otherAV.m_year;
        m_finalprice = otherAV.m_finalprice;
        SetOwner(NULL);
        for(auto i = otherAV.m_sensors.begin(); i != otherAV.m_sensors.end(); i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            AddSensor(otherAV.m_sensors[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    AdvancedVehicle& operator=(const AdvancedVehicle& otherAV) {
        m_model = otherAV.m_model;
        m_year = otherAV.m_year;
        setPrice(otherAV.GetPrice());
        SetOwner(otherAV.GetOwner());
        for(auto i = otherAV.m_sensors.begin(); i != otherAV.m_sensors.end(); i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            AddSensor(otherAV.m_sensors[j]);
            j++;
        }

        return *this;
    }
    void AddSensor(Sensor addedSensor) {
        m_sensors.push_back(addedSensor);
        m_finalprice += addedSensor.GetPrice();
    }
    virtual float GetPrice() const { return m_finalprice; }
    virtual void Serialize(ostream& os) const {
        os << m_year << " ";
        os << m_model << " ";
        os << m_finalprice << " ";
        if(GetOwner() != NULL)
        {
            os << GetOwner() << " ";
        }
        for(auto i = m_sensors.begin(); i != m_sensors.end(); i++)
        {
            os << &i << " ";
        }
        os << endl;
    }

private:
    vector<Sensor> m_sensors;
    float m_finalprice;
};
```

Comment: I doubt that's the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: To ensure that derived class overrides your virtual function use "override" keyword.

Comment: Please show the code with the objects on which you invoke `Serialize`.

Comment: There is so much fluff in the post that is unrelated to the core problem. The mantra for posting on SO ought to be mcve, mcve, mcve ([mcve]).

Answer (score 2):

Your program is suffering from [the object slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). The `operator<<` takes a `Vehicle` object *by value*. This means a new `Vehicle` object is copy-constructed from the argument passed to the operator. The new object is a `Vehicle`, not an `AdvancedVehicle`, even if what was passed to the operator was an `AdvancedVehicle`. The object is said to have been *sliced* and this is why the base version of the `Serialize()` function is called.

To address this, you should modify the `operator<<` overload to take a `Vehicle` by reference (`Vehicle&`). This will eliminate the copy and the slicing.

Comment: const reference (`const Vehicle&`).  Also, there should not be an `operator <<` for AdvancedVehicle.

Comment: Downvoting because this was a really crappy question.  (The OP didn't show the calls to the serialize, and they had made no attempt to minimize the example).  Answering questions like this, just encourages them.